# pushing $id value into array value

Tags: php, arrays

I want to push id value into array.I want to push $id value with  $alid.I want to merge the value.

I want to get
`$alid = {"id":"1638926145", "album_desc":"dfgdgdfg", "content_type":"alb_detail", "website_id":"571710720", "user":"admin@gmail.com", "album_title":"fdgfdgfdg", "album_creation_date":"2015-11-23T05:27:03.806Z"}`

```
while($fet_alb = mysql_fetch_array($get_alb)) {
    $id=$fet_alb['ID'];
    $alid=$fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE'];

   $alb[]= json_decode($fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE']);
}
$id=1638926145 
$alid={"album_desc":"dfgdgdfg","content_type":"alb_detail","website_id":"571710720","user":"admin@gmail.com","album_title":"fdgfdgfdg","album_creation_date":"2015-11-23T05:27:03.806Z"}
```

Comment: what is the issue with what you are trying to do?

Comment: is it something like `$alb[] => array('id' = $id, 'content' => json_decode($fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`$alb[] = array_merge(array('id' => $id), json_decode($fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE'], true));`

Here I have converted the JSON to array and then created another array having `id` and then merged both the arrays to give one single array as output.

**EDIT**

`$array1 = array('id' => $id); // creating a array with only a ID`

`$array2 = json_decode($fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE'], true); // converting JSON to array with content`

`$alb[] = array_merge($array1, $array2); // Merge both arrays to single array`

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$data['id']=$fet_alb['ID'];
$data['alid'] = $fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE'];

$alb[]= json_decode($data);
```

Comment: $data is not JSON, its array as you have shown. `$fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE']` is only JSON so you cannot `json_decode` and array.

Comment: Instead of just writing "Use this or that" you might actually want to explain _WHY_ the OP should use it and what the code is meant to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$id = $fet_alb['ID']
$alid = json_decode($fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE']);
$alid['id'] = $id;
// to get JSON string
echo json_encode($alid);
```

Comment: In order to access `$alid` this way you need to pass the `true` parameter to `json_decode`, else you get an object.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `id` property or array element to the result of `json_decode` result then do an `json_encode` to encode back to `json`

See below

```
while($fet_alb = mysql_fetch_array($get_alb)) {
    $id=$fet_alb['ID'];
    $alid=$fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE'];

    /* using an object from json_decode*/
    $alb= json_decode($fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE']);
    $alb->id = $id; //or directly 
    $alb->id = $fet_alb['ID'];

    /*or using an associative array from json_decode*/
    $alb= json_decode($fet_alb['CONTENT_VALUE'],true);
    $alb['id'] = $id; //or directly 
    $alb['id'] = $fet_alb['ID'];



    /* construct the final json string */
    $jsonString = json_encode($alb);
    var_dump($jsonString);
    /* will output
    string(194) "{
       "album_desc":"dfgdgdfg", 
       "content_type":"alb_detail", 
       "website_id":"571710720", 
       "user":"admin@gmail.com", 
       "album_title":"fdgfdgfdg", 
       "album_creation_date":"2015-11-23T05:27:03.806Z", 
       "id":1638926145
    }"
    */
}
```